# Metric spaces - $(0, 1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are not isometric

Tags: metric-spaces, isometry

I'm looking for alternative solutions to what I currently have for the sake of self studying to the following:

> Show that $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are not isometric, where both sets are equipped with the standard $d_2$ metric.

Current solution:

> $d(0, 2) = 2$ in $\mathbb{R}$, but $d(f(0), f(2))$ is at most $1$ in $(0,1)$.

Comment: If it's a requirement for me to add the reason why I'm looking for an alternative solution to prevent this from being flagged for some reason then I shall do so.

Comment: I'd say your solution is optimal, assuming that $f$ is an arbitrary function $\Bbb R\to(0,1)$ that you're trying to prove isn't an isometry. The only tweak I would offer is "less than $1$" instead of "at most $1$." What makes you want another?

Comment: Well, if this were an exam situation, I'd be too flustered assuming for a contradiction that there was an isometry $f$ and playing around with some $\delta$ near $0$ and some $\varepsilon$ near $1$ and trying to show something about their distance under $f$. The current solution takes $f$ to go from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0,1)$ rather than the order stated in the question, so it feels a bit misleading (again, if this were an exam I don't think I'd see this nice solution).

Comment: $(0,1)$ is bounded, $\mathbb  R$ isn't.

Comment: @Santiago What does this mean? I don't think that being bounded is a topological property unfortunately so I can't easily disprove the isometry by saying that the two spaces aren't homeomorphic.

Comment: @IrregularUser: True, boundedness isn't a property of the topology. However, it *s* a property of the *metric*.

Comment: @CameronBuie What does it mean to be a property of a metric? Is it similar to being a topological property, except for a metric?

Comment: @IrregularUser It's a metric property if: whenever $(X,d)$ has the property and it is bijectively isometric to $(Y,d')$ then $Y$ also has the property.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks, I wasn't aware of the definition at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isometries preserve boundedness, completeness and total boundedness, among other things.

$(0,1)$ is totally bounded and bounded, the reals are not.

$(0,1)$ is not complete ($\frac{1}{n}$ is Cauchy but does not converge) and the reals are.

Comment: Does this also mean that $\mathbb{R}$ is not isometric to $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: @TaylorRendon yes, indeed. They’re not uniformly equivalent.

Comment: Could you also say that $\mathbb{R}$ is not isometric to $(0,\infty)$ because the identity does not establish an isometry between the two sets?

Comment: @TaylorRendon it’s easier to note that if they had been isometric, they’d be simultaneously complete. And $\Bbb $$ is and $(0,\infty)$ is not.